# Using Ansible with sudo su

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to setup Ansible to access our infrastructure from and admin account. With not much success.

I need to login to our RedHat servers with my user "my_user". then we need to switch to a admin user "sudo su - admin_user"

From my Workstation:

```
ssh my_user@server1.com (doesn't need a password)
```

From Server1.com

```
sudo su - admin_user (requires password)
```

thanks

--------- Tried ---------

-> Tried adding to playbook yaml file

```
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  become_user: admin_user
```

-> Error
fatal: [server1.com] => Missing become password

-> Tried adding to ansible.cfg file

```
[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method='sudo'
become_user='admin_user'
become_ask_pass=true
```

-> Error
fatal: [server1.com] => Internal Error: this module does not support running commands via 'sudo'

Comment: which module are you trying to run?

Comment: basic playlist module: - hosts: test
  tasks:
  - name: pwd
    command: /bin/pwd

Answer (score 1):

> Error fatal: [server1.com] => Missing become password

is a reasonably clear error message — you need to provide a password to the [`become` option](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) ([previously `sudo`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#sudo-and-su-still-work)) .

You can do this directly on the command line when calling `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` with [`--ask-become-pass`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#new-command-line-options) like so:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/test site.yml --ask-become-pass
```

which will provide a secure password prompt for you to enter it.

Or alternatively this can be provided by the variable `ansible_become_pass`.